# How to open cart items by default on the shipping step, but hide them on the payment step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4.3.p1

In app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html the collapsible widget is initiated via:

```
    <div class="block items-in-cart"
        data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">... 
    </div>
```

As you know there are 2 steps in the checkout. I need the active state to be `true` on the shipping step and to be `false` on the payment step.

I read somewhere that `stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping')` returns `false` on the shipping step and `true` on the payment step, so I created a mixin for the `cart-items.js`:

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'], function (stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
            return !stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

I therefore expect it to return `true` (--> `!false`) on shipping and `false` on the payment step. However, this doesnt work. It also gives me a `knockout.js:3620 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.` error on the payment step.

I also tried to be clever using vanilla javascript in `cart-items.html` but that didnt work either.

So how can I dynamically set the active state for the collapsible widget (depending on the step)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution: You basically click the Continue button with Jquery and then hide the respective step/steps with CSS

> (/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css):

```
#checkout, #payment-method {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: ? I dont understand (it doesnt make any sense). It should be doable with Knockout though.

Comment: Yes, you can hide the desired data with knockout js